# jQuery: Adding additional pixels to the scrollTop

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following code to smooth the movement when user clicks on a link that its `href` starts with an "#"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

I need to add about 40px to the scrollTop value, so the stopping point doe snot cover the content. I modified the code to this, but it does not seem to be doing it (notice the +40 towards end of the code):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + 40
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You added `+ 40` in the right place. What is it happening?

Comment: I just added that 40 back, take a look please. No matter what value I add, it stops at the same location.

Comment: Have you verified that `$target.offset().top` returns the expected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+40` offset which you actually want to be a `-40` is not working because once the animation is complete the browser is doing it's default reaction of going to the element with the `id` you are passing to `window.location.hash`

You can either remove that line or add the following css to the elements being scrolled to.

```
padding-top: 40px;
margin-top: -40px;
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/ALryC/1/)

Comment: Thanks, followed your suggestion and tweaked my js to add a class of "targeted" to my target; however, even though I can adjust the css for my ".targeted" div, the page will not look alright if people start to verticall scroll up and down, because they will see the gap added by my css. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Is the `window.location.hash = target;` line critical for some other function in your code?

Comment: No it's not. It can be removed.

Comment: Then, I would just remove that line, and your code will work as expected as long as you change it to `-40` offset. :) Best of Luck!

Answer (score 22):

I know a late answer but someone seeking a solution can try this.

By adding .top + (-40) will do the trick

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top + (-40)
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
});
```

Comment: This is a way better solution, not messing with css classes switching.

Comment: This doesnt work for me, once the smooth animation to an alement is complete it makes an extra snap-back at the very end.